# Not able to install eclipse plugin packaged as an eclipse update site

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, installation

Hello everyone,

I have a zip file for a plugin and I am supposed to install the same by using Eclipse -> help -> install new software in the same way as we do by adding software update site. However, I am not able to do so and I am getting the below error. Please check the screenshots and guide me as to what I am doing wrong.

I tried checking on the web and it seems everyone does the same step as mine. But somehow it is not working for me.

Operating System : Windows 7 32-bit
Site: https://seallab.wikispaces.com/Running+Sydit+and+LASE
Eclipse: helios 3.6

I am trying to install the software by following the steps on the website : https://seallab.wikispaces.com/Running+Sydit+and+LASE

I am trying to do the below step of this tutorial:

```
Required projects
LASE and Sydit are packaged as an eclipse update site. you can unzip the size and install LASE from the help>install new software menu.
lase_update.ziplase_update.zip
DetailsDownload14 MB
```

Screenshot of eclipse :

[image: Screenshot of eclipse]

Contents of zip file:

[image: Contents of zip file]

Appreciate your help. Thanks .

Comment: It seem you missed part of the instructions from the tutorial, it asked you to unzip the zip file first. PS Helios is quite an old Eclipse version, you may be required to use it, but if not I would consider starting with something a little more modern Mars - 2015, Luna - 2014, Kepler - 2013, Luna - 2012, Juno - 2011: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)#Releases

Answer (score 2):

Manually unzip the file to a directory of your choice. That directory then is the local update site to use for loading the plugin.